# How to find features from edge_id in PostGIS topology?

Tags: postgis, spatial-query, postgis-topology

I have created topology for a set of tables with PostGIS topology extension.

Now, I want to get all linear features (which could be in different tables) connected to a particular line using a non-spatial query.

why non-spatial? because it is much faster than spatial queries and I am using topology extension because I want to avoid spatial queries and functions like `ST_DWithin` , `ST_Intersects` or even `ST_Touches`.

So far,I know how to find the edge_id of the lines that are connected to my PARTICULAR_LINE with the following statement:

```
 SELECT e2.edge_id,e2.start_node,e2.end_node
 FROM elec_topo.edge_data as e1
 INNER JOIN elec_topo.edge_data as e2
     ON (e1.start_node = e2.end_node or  e1.end_node = e2.start_node or 
         e1.start_node = e2.start_node or  e1.end_node = e2.end_node) 
         and e1.edge_id = (select unnest(GetTopoGeomElementArray(topo_geom)) 
                                 from PARTICULAR_LINE_TABLE 
                                     where id=40);
```

The question is : How to find the respective features of these edge_ids?

There is however one silly way that I can think of to find features out of there edge_ids and that is to find topogeo_id and layer_id of each edge_id (by querying the `relation` table), and then using layer_id to find the name of each feature table by querying the `Layer` table and finally querying those feature tables (with topogeo_id).But this will take ages, is this really the only non-spatial way to do it?

As far as I have understood, there is no non-spatial way to do so, I really hope that I am wrong about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible without using spatial functions, however instead of approaching the solution from a query/output perspective, maybe approach from a data capture/storage perspective.
eg: store the spatial relations in a new table (eg: connected) which gets populated on insert/update triggers, based on ST_Intersects (or similar).

This would enable:

- the time expensive ST_Intersects operations to only be called during data capture/insertion (ie: once!).
- the topology results can be stored as a non-spatial relation which can then be navigated using normal relational queries, thus improved query performance as you say.
- Allow topology to exist across different tables table1.recA intersects table2.recB = true.

Downsides:

- This is a massive piece of work and may not warrant the effort, depending upon how much data you have.
- Your data model will be much more complex than what it is now.
- You will have to run all insert triggers on your loaded data (or reload your data).
- More code = More bugs, etc etc.
- In all honesty, my above suggestion is really in line with commercial solutions that are available, ie: why build when you can buy.

Also with regards to your SQL statement, this is making an assumption that the linear features only join at their end nodes. What about lines that intersect in the middle? What about curved lines? Do you have a tolerance for intersection? (1m? 1cm? 1mm?) These are all the advantages of ST_Intersects and associated geometry based queries.
It may be worthwhile posting a picture of what type of intersections you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1, Will accept it if no other better answer comes up.

Comment: Regarding your answer, Yes I am aware that it only handles ending nodes cause I just want to connect the end nodes. And regarding your suggestion to buy a commercial product, We already have this abilities in GE Smallworld but there are a lot of restrictions when you are using a GIS solution that has a propertiery database. So, it looks like that I should implement my own topological model (with the same core concept of you answer). I also don’t think implementing this would take more than 2 days.

Comment: The reason that I have posted this question was because I wanted to use a standard topological model (complying iso sql mm) so I would be able to use other libraries. But looks like I can’t!

Comment: ooo I jut read your profile - I also started learning SW back in 2006 so we are both talking the same language! …. …. I previously experienced the restrictions that you mention, but I did find with their new versions of products, getting answers was much much easier and didn't require development (or less development).......... obviously this very much depends on what type of solutions you are trying to build etc..... I had a lot of experience deploying customer driven solutions through the SWAF framework and also through GSA, so am happy to share those in another discussion.

Comment: Great, I am looking forward to hear from you soon.